# padding attributes for custom views

Tags: android, properties, adt, android-custom-view

I created a custom view for my first Android app (a custom progress bar) by "XYZ extends View".
The custom view itself works fine, but i cant see the standard attributes that should be inherited from the class View (e.g. padding) in the ADT layout editor.

I tried to set them by XML and i realy can use them in my cutom view.

Why aint they shown in the attribute list?
Also, my custom view is not shown in the list of "Custom & library views"